# Stripe charge or plan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, this is my create action for my charges controller:

```
def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 100

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:email],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
      Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount => @amount,
          :currency => 'usd',
          :customer => customer.id,
          :description => 'Example charge custom form'
      )
      redirect_to root_path

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    current_user.subscribed = true
    current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
    current_user.save


    flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing. Your account has been unlocked."
end
```

I want to do something like `current_user.end_date = (a month from now)`. Not actually sure how to do this.

Then I would check if `current_user.end_date` is in the future every time the individual logs in. If it's not, I make `current_user.subscribed = false`.

Is this possible, and if so, would you be able to walk me through this because I'm not understanding how to use time too well in rails. Or should I consider doing this as a plan? I wasn't sure because I don't want recurring billing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time), this should exactly be

```
1.month.from_now
```